# Getting TypeError: argument: 'self' missing, while working with poetry and CLI

Tags: python, command-line-interface, typeerror, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

1. I am using poetry and sys.argv.
2. I wrote the code in a OOP manner.
3. While I am running code from CLI, I am getting an error as shown below.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

4. I am taking argument from CLI and passing it to my script as mentioned below.

```
list_of_ticker = sys.argv[1].split(',')
print(list_of_ticker)

foo = CalculateEtfsYahoo(list_of_ticker)
foo.main()
```

FYI,

1. The code is working, only after expected output I am getting above mentioned error.
2. Also, I have added the module.pakage:class.function in pyproject.toml as shown below.
   `[tool.poetry.scripts] findata = "investment.ParseFinData:CalculateEtfsYahoo.main"`
3. When I am replacing above point 2 with "module.package:class"

   `[tool.poetry.scripts] findata = "investment.ParseFinData:CalculateEtfsYahoo"`

And giving CLI command like this: `poetry run findata.main <argument>`
then, I am getting error as
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: CalculateEtfsYahoo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list_of_ticker'`

I do not know how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Paste your entire code here.

Answer (score 0):

if everyrthing is working and you just want to get rid of the error you could use

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=TypeError) #I'm not sure this is the correct category but change it if needed.
```